# Python Multiprocessing, Difference between Process and Pool, Pickling of Data

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I am wondering what is the difference between starting a Pool of workers to manage a task in parallel or to start individual processes when it comes to pickling and distributing jobs.

I do have a task (here `do_my_job`) whose objects cannot be pickled. Thus, I cannot start a pool of workers to execute the task in parallel. The following snippet does NOT work, where `iterator` iterates over different parameters settings for `do_my_job`:

```
import multiprocessing as multip

mpool = multip.Pool(ncores)
mpool.map(do_my_job, iterator)
mpool.close()
mpool.join()
```

Yet, the following code snippet DOES work:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as multip

keep_running=True
process_list = []

while len(process_list)>0 or keep_running:

    terminated_procs = []
    for idx, proc in enumerate(process_list):

        if not proc.is_alive():
            terminated_procs.append(idx)

    for terminated_proc in terminated_procs:
        process_list.pop(terminated_proc)

    if len(process_list) < ncores and keep_running:
        try:
            task = iterator.next()
            proc = multip.Process(target=do_my_job,
                                                   args=(task,))

            proc.start()
            process_list.append(proc)
        except StopIteration:
            keep_running=False


    time.sleep(0.1)
```

How is my job in the latter case distributed to the individual processes? Is there not step of pickling the task and all related objects involved before a process is started? If not how are the task and objects passed to the new processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `fork` a new process the child process will inherit his parent data. So, if the parent defines a variable *before* forking, the child will be able to see it as it were its own variable. After the `fork` syscall child and parent process should use some IPC to share data between them.
When you create a `Pool` you are forking N processes, then, when you call `map`, you pass them your data. But, because the processes were already forked, the only way to share this data is using IPC which involves "pickling" the object. In the latter case you are forking *after* creating the data, so the child process is able to access it as it where its own.
I think that the best thing that you could do would be to make your object "pickable".

Comment: The inherited data is copied, right? So whatever the child process does to the data does not modify the data of the parent class?! 
Unfortunately, I cannot make the my object "pickable" since parts of it are from a third party application.

Comment: Usually it is "copy-on-write". The child and the parent will share the same "memory" until one of them try to write, then a copy is made.

Comment: @SmCaterpillar, how does your main program get access to these 3rd-party objects?  You could use the same kind of code in your Pool processes to access them, perhaps in a process initialization function. Not enough detail here to flesh it out. At an extreme, you could pass code to access them as a *string*, and `exec` that string in a Pool process. There are always alternatives ;-)

Comment: I am writing an API to allow easier data storage and handling of BRIAN (http://briansimulator.org/) experiments. The API should allow easy parallel processing of several BRIAN networks. This must handle cases of the networks being pre-built and pre-run before the parallel parameter exploration. The problem is that sometimes BRIAN networks cannot be pickled. Accordingly, all pool processes would need to rebuilt the network. Sometimes this is too costly, especially when you can do this once instead of a thousand times. I mean how much worse than using a pool is my code suggestion from above?

Comment: This is a difficult question, you should do some test, maybe using `timeit`.

Comment: One minor question. If the data is copied via *copy-on-write* on which level is that happening? Is that python related (if so why not pickle?) or does that happen much more low level, i.e. this more or less platform specific?